# Romanization of ㅚ in Duolingo

Tags: vowel

Sometimes Duolingo romanizes ㅚ as oe, and sometimes as we, I wonder what the difference come from? For example 최소 is romanized as choeso and 왼 is romanized as wen. [I guess it might be because it's pronounced similarly to ㅞ](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/615/pronunciation-of-%E3%85%9A), but Duolingo should be consistent, otherwise it makes it harder for learners.

What am I missing here?

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't be using Romanization to learn Korean.  Once you learned the characters, ditch Romanization.  Otherwise you're wasting your time, practicing with a system that nobody uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duolingo is trying to guide learners to correct pronunciation by using Romanization that mimics English phonetics. However, they are also trying to dabble in following a standardized Romanization system for Korean. Romanizing ㅚ as oe is in keeping with the 2000 Revised Romanization of Korean system. However, it is rather ambiguous as to how to pronounce 'oe' if the learner's only point of reference is English phonetics. Hence the use of 'we' as well.

I agree that it is confusing. This is a great demonstration as to why Korean language learners need to get away from Romanized learning as soon as they feasibly can.